# Middleware Invoke called only on Request (but not on Response)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

I have a controller action that when called from client goes through the `JwtMiddleware` `Invoke` method. But when I return from the action using `BaseController` `Ok` method method `Invoke` is not called. Is that correct behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. As described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-class) the middleware class must include:

> - A public constructor with a parameter of type `RequestDelegate`.
> - A public method named `Invoke` or `InvokeAsync`. This method must:
>
>   - Return a `Task`.
>   - Accept a first parameter of type `HttpContext`.

And sample `Invoke(Async)` method can look like this:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    // Do something before the next delegate/middleware
    // ...

    // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline. 
    // (actually can be not invoked in some cases, i.e. if request is already handled by current middleware)
    await _next(context);

    // Do something after the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline has finished.
    // ...
}
```

So the pipeline is architectured in a way that the `Invoke(Async)` method itself is called once per middleware registration during the request, but it can handle/process the request before and after next registered delegate/middleware in the pipeline.

There is another alternative to middlewares for MVC (they are introduced for [Minimal APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/min-api-filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0) in not released yet .NET 7 also but look more like endpoint specific middlewares) called [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0) which allow to distinguish between before and after action execution:

[image]

```cs
public class SampleActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Do something before the action executes.
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // Do something after the action executes.
    }
}
```

Comment: So `Invoke` is never called in the `Response` direction? Only in the `Request` direction is that right?

Comment: @user19564787 I would argue that it is not fully correct idea of middleware pipeline. In general case there is no request and response direction in terms of `Invoke` invocations, middlewares basically are a single linked list where every item in pipeline calls next one's `Inkove`.

Comment: @user19564787 and every middleware "decides" what it wants to do before and/or after the next one is invoked.  For example auth or jwt middleware it makes sense to do something before invoking the next one, for exception handling one - after invoking the next, for some request-response logging middleware it makes sense to log before and after the next pipeline.

Comment: @user19564787 In theory a middleware can invoke next one after it has already handled request and started writing the response (though I doubt that this is a usual case though).

Comment: So when is the middleware called - before `Request` or it can be called at any time? If Invoke method contains `HttpContext` it would make sense that it is called at some point of time during execution of `Request` or `Response`. Am I right? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user19564787 they are invoked on the request to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

So It works like this

```
 public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("during request"); // Executed during request
     await _next(context);
     Console.WriteLine("during response"); // Executed during response
 }
```

**_next(context);** immediately calls the next middleware and code after that is executed while returning response.

Comment: So then why httpContext.Response.HasStarted returns false if I put after the await _next?